# Does WebElement.find_element_by_class_name searches only in immediate children [WebDriver/Python]

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

According to the [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element_by_class_name) find_element_by_class_name "Finds element within this element’s children by class name."

It's not clear whether this method looks for a matching element only among the immediate children of the `WebElement` or in its entire subtree.

Answer (score 2):

As the doc says,

*Finds element within this element’s children by class name.*

if you use `find_element_by_class_name` on a *WebElement* it will ONLY find the elements that are children to the parent element.

On the other hand, if you use it on driver instance, it will find all the matching of the page.

Comment: suppose I want to find an descendant element (that is somewhere in the subtree not necessarily  an immediate children) by its class_name. How can I do that?

Comment: It will find ALL children not caring there position. It actually depends on how you write the selector mostly

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I have an element X. I want to find ALL element that are somewhere in the subtree rooted at X (that is: not necessarily direct children) by their class name.  Can it be done?

Comment: Sure. But, let me ask you this: why you need to use class only? You have more control over how you find elements using css and xpath as well

Answer (score 1):

You can do either really... it depends on how you construct the initial CSS selector.

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table > tr")); // finds only TRs that are immediate children of a TABLE tag.
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table tr")); // finds *all* TRs that are children of a TABLE tag.
```

I refer to this often as a reference when using CSS selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors. These two cases are described near the bottom of this list:

E F - an F element descendant of an E element - Descendant combinator

E > F - an F element child of an E element - Child combinator

Answer (score 0):

*disclosure: this is essentially just a merge of the existing answers, both of which are separately helpful and I upvoted, to more directly answer the question and save future readers some scanning time*

The WebElement 'find by id/classname' api **does only search within the element's immediate children**. This behaviour is common between the various webdriver implementations, though is not particularly well documented.

The best and seemingly webdriver-idiomatic way to search a particular element's entire subtree is therefore to use the driver's 'find element by css selector/xpath' api, rather than trying to chain WebElement findElement calls, finding a parent first then searching its subtree as a separate operation.

To be honest, the resulting code is much cleaner - css selectors (and xpath) are far more concise and elegant for the reader to parse than a chain of such calls, essentially giving you the same power with a much terser syntax.

It may be that restricting the search to immediate children in the WebElement 'find by id/classname' apis was a design choice in the api for exactly this purpose, as well as to maximise explicitness and avoid unintended searching of an element's entire subtree.